# Why can't an array ever be null?

Tags: c++, arrays

Consider the following program:

```
int main() {

  int* arr[5];

  if (arr == nullptr) {
     std::cout << "arr is null" << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Why is the message `arr is null` not printed out? `arr` is uninitialized, so it makes no sense. Moreover, whenever I print an element from the array, it gives me `0`.

If I dynamically allocate an array and delete it afterwards, then check to see if it is a null pointer like the example above, the message `arr is null` still does not print.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and if there is a way we can set arrays to null pointers?

Comment: *arr is uninitialized so it makes no sense* -- Uninitialized doesn't mean it is `nullptr`.

Comment: an array **is not a pointer**.   They might decay into pointers but they are not. All arrays haver a well defined and unchangeable value.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you provide any article or official documentation which backs this up? Because the current c++ course that I am following is created by a youtuber called "The Cherno" and he mentions how arrays are just a pointer and that arr[i] is just syntax sugar over the following *(arr + offset)

Comment: @HumblePenguin The variable contains a pointer to the first element of the array. The pointer to the array isn't the same as the array itself. All the pointer does is tell you where you can find the array in memory. (The bit about `arr[i]` is true, though, AFAIK, with the disclaimer that I've been out of C++ for quite awhile now).

Comment: @HumblePenguin -- *Because the current c++ course that I am following is created by a youtuber* -- All the youtuber described is how internally arrays are represented.  In C++, arrays and pointers are different *types* -- they are not the same thing.

Comment: `arr` is an array containing 5 uninitialized pointer. `arr == nullptr` causes `arr` to decay to a pointer to the first element, that is a pointer to an uninitialized pointer. `arr` itself is not initialized, only the elements it contains are uninitialized.

Comment: Any [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should cover this.  I strongly suggest learning C++ from one of those than youtube.  there is just too much bad advice out there from people that don't really know C++, like the person you are using.  If an array was a pointer then `sizeof(array_name) would never change but since it does (larger arrays have larger size), it proves it is not a pointer.  here is what thew standard says: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array

Comment: *"arr is uninitialized so it makes no sense"* If `arr` actually was an unitialized variable, then the only thing that makes no sense is to have any expectation about its value, such as expecting it to be `nullptr`. Unititialized objects are, by definition, not necessarily initialized to a null-like value.

Comment: @HumblePenguin What would you expect from this code: `{ int a; if (a == 0) {} }`?  What is the value of `a`?  Is it 0?  This is analogous to expecting an uninitialized pointer to be `nullptr`.

Comment: A simple little experiment would be informative to the learner here: try assigning null to the array, such as `arr = nullptr` - Then find out, does it even compile? That'll tell you very quickly that there is at least some difference between an array and a pointer (even if they can be used similarly in other circumstances).

Comment: Too many negatives in the question - an array __can__ never be null.  Or it __cannot__ ever be null.

Comment: `arr` has a non-null address, so tests not equal to null.   Its elements (five `int *`s) are uninitialised.  Accessing their values (e.g. `std::cout << static_cast<void *>(arr[0])`) gives undefined behaviour.   Modifying the values of an uninitialised element (e.g. `arr[0] = new int [10];`_ is fine, and allows them to subsequently be used.

Comment: `std::cout << arr << "\n";` will print the address of the `arr` variable.  The `arr` variable's address is not null.  The `arr` variable is an array of 5 pointers to int.  None of the 5 pointers have been initialized yet.  `int* arr[5]{};` would have initialized them to `nullptr`, but since the code doesn't read any of those array elements, it's okay for them to not be initialized (I just like to always initialize variables when I declare them... my pet peeve).

Comment: @Peter FYI, that kind of `static_cast` is only needed for `char*` pointers. You can pass an `int*` to `operator<<(void*)` without casting it.

Comment: Why the downvotes and delete vote? This seems like a perfectly reasonable question for a beginner to ask, and it is certainly answerable.

Comment: "*Why is the message `arr is null` not printed out?*" - because `arr` is not a pointer. It has storage in memory, so it has a memory address. It *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element, and so can never decay to `nullptr`. "*`arr` is uninitialized*" - its *elements* are uninitialized, the array itself is not. "*If I dynamically allocate an array and delete it afterwards, then check to see if it is a null pointer ..., the message `arr is null` still does not print*" - the allocation returns a pointer to the memory. Freeing the memory does not update the pointer, you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from this:

```cpp
int main() {
  int* arr[5];
...
```

Assume we are compiling on a 32 bit architecture and variables are on the stack. What is the type of `arr`? It is an array of five pointers to int. It means that `arr` is a name that you use to refer to 20 bytes on your stack, and every four bytes are the address of an int. It contains 5 numbers and definitely is not `nullptr`. Every time I access `arr` I use address A1B2C3D4 on my system. (This is just an example number. Try on your system and check what is that address. Then on next execution it will be probably different)

What is contained in those 20 bytes? Let's see:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|0FF13456|7ACC77BB|CB48A3EC|175FFFEF|BBCC87A1|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Why? It's just some leftovers from who knows what previous use of the stack.

Are they valid addresses? Probably (very likely) not. It is better to initialize your pointers to `nullptr` so that you can check them.

```cpp
int main() {
  int* arr[5] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
...
```

Is `arr` nullptr now? No. It's still A1B2C3D4.

Test this like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    int* arr[5] = { nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
    if (arr == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "arr is null\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] is null\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can also write:

```
int* arr[5] = {};
```

or

```
int* arr[5]{};
```